# twitter4j oauth doesn't work on some devices

Tags: android, oauth, twitter4j

I have an application which uses twitter4j to authenticate users. 
Oauth didn't work till I set setUseSsl(true);

```
ConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
        configurationBuilder.setOAuthConsumerKey(TWITTER_OAUTH_CONSUMER_KEY);
        configurationBuilder.setOAuthConsumerSecret(TWITTER_OAUTH_CONSUMER_SECRET);
        configurationBuilder.setUseSSL(true);
```

Now it works on devices 50/50. Some devices complains about authentication with error

```
TwitterException{exceptionCode=[6f0f59ca-225271ef 1de2170b-27fbc7b7], statusCode=-1, message=null, code=-1, retryAfter=-1, rateLimitStatus=null, version=3.0.5}
```

Can anyone help me with it?

Comment: Are you using the latest Twitter4J Jar files ? Recently they had some updation in their services so all old jars files are not working now.

Comment: Yes, I use v3.0.5 this is the last one.

Comment: Are there examples for android? All I've found is very old and don't use setUseSsl(true) and oauth doesn't work without this flag.

Comment: I dont think you need any example for it. Just download the latest .Jar file and include them in your project and done. :)

Comment: Do you have an application working with twitter oauth and ssl? Is it works fine? If it is, I will find troubles in my project. Cant you check please?

Comment: No sorry, I do not have such application. I just read it in other question posts.